# WCF all clients use web.config values regardless of settings provided by clients

Tags: c#, wcf

We have several clients (10s) who connect with our WCF server using endpoints, at the moment they are all using this code give below.

**Can we specify all settings in our web.config e.g. as our WCF web services are hosted on a separate server and just ignore what client provides us, I want them to not provide us values like time outs and bindings, I looked at certificate authentication but not what we want as client will increase in future..**

```
        HttpClientCredentialType credType = myCred.httpClientCredentialType;

        //Set the binding security & authentication type
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = credType;

        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0);
        binding.CloseTimeout = ts;
        binding.OpenTimeout = ts;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = ts;
        binding.SendTimeout = ts;

        //set the webservice endpoint address
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(someURL + "/_vti_bin/ourWCF/fruits.svc");

        ChannelFactory<WebServices.Internal.IFruits> factory = new ChannelFactory<WebServices.Internal.IFruits>(binding);
        factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = myCred;
        factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = myCred.UserName;
        factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = myCred.Password;

        WebServices.Internal.IFruits proxy = factory.CreateChannel(endpoint);
        string someThing = proxy.GetFruitsList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only control your own host settings; you can't control what the client's do. If they want to set their connection timeout to 1 second, there's nothing you as the host administrator/program can do about that. Unless ...

If you have enough control over your would-be clients to insist that they use your client-side DLL/Exe to make and maintain connectivity with your host, then you can set the client-side configuration the way you want to. But if you've got iOS, Android, Windows, etc. clients all hitting your service from places all over the world, you're stuck with whatever client-side configuration they're using.